# String or binary data would be truncated - Msg 8152

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem trying to update rows in a table. I'm getting an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

However, I've double checked the length of the data being inserted and the column lengths and they are all within parameters, so I'm at a loss as to what may be causing it.

It's just a simple update statement across every row in the table that looks like this:

```
UPDATE [tblAssets]
SET [DepartmentID] = 'B13F3C7B7489';
```

The tblAssets.DepartmentID column is a char, so I don't understand how I could possibly be getting a truncate error.

The column definition reads:

```
[DepartmentID] [char](20) NULL
```

My account has administrative privileges across the server, so it's not a rights issue.  I've even tried creating a variable and loading it with the appropriate data from another table through a select statement, but that doesn't work either.

I am able to manually cut-paste that data into individual records, but it will not let me perform an update through a SQL query into the table.  The server is MS SQL 2008 R2.

- This problem has been solved.  There was a trigger at the table level that I was not aware of.  Answer below.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: no, there are no triggers, and no key constraints on that column.

Comment: Well then you're going to have to try to reproduce the issue on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). With the information we have right now, this error should not happen, so something is missing.

Comment: Obviously it should not be happening LOL - that's the problem.  I doubt I'll be able to reproduce it.  I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Well SQL Server doesn't invent this error for fun, it is really happening, you just haven't given enough information to determine where.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know man.  I just tried manually cutting and pasting the data into the DepartmentID field for a few records and that worked fine, so I know I can write to the table.  It just won't let me do an update on it.

Comment: I think that error should not appear with the information that you was posted. Please post the script of **tblAssets** table. Or try use this [tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/), create a table, insert some values, and try to update.

Comment: How would you like me to post that?  Cut and paste the create script into the question?

Comment: Maybe there is a computed column?

Comment: @MichaelSuede I copied and pasted your query but i don't have any error, because there is nothing wrong!, so try to execute your queries on this [tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/), create a table tblAssets, insert values and then update. Check that and then tell us how you did.

Comment: Yeah it works fine, and I know there is nothing wrong.  I don't think this has anything to do with the query itself.  I'm posting here because I want to know if there is something I might have overlooked as far as server settings may be concerned.  If I create a table and do an update on it, it runs just fine.

Comment: Could you try padding the DepartmentID with spaces so that it is 20 characters long and see if you still get the same error?

Comment: Yep, I tried padding the data too.  That didn't work.

Comment: I still think you should double- and triple-check for triggers.

Comment: Yep, please run the following query: `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE parent_id = object_id('tblAssets')`

Comment: Look at that, I got three hits when I ran it. My triggers folder is empty, so I assumed there were no triggers.

Comment: Ok, so fix your trigger. Case closed.

Comment: Double check if you were looking in triggers folder under the correct table and right click -> refresh on it.

Comment: My triggers folder for the DB is empty, even after a restart and refresh.

Comment: Why are you looking for database-level triggers? Table triggers are table-specific. So you look under `Tables > the table > Triggers`.

Comment: Please try execute this `SELECT * FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'DepartmentID'`, and check the value of the `lenght` field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to take a wild guess that somehow you snuck a unicode or invisible character into your update string value:   you get that same error message when trying to update a regular character (or varchar) field with unicode data.

Comment: I tested this several ways.  First, I'm able to manually cut-paste the data, so that right there says the data string must be valid.  I've also tried to load it with a variable from the department table, so that data also has been validated.  I know the string must be valid, so I highly doubt it's the data.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was a trigger on the table for updates.  This trigger did not show up in the triggers folder for the database.  Running this statement showed them to me:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE parent_id = object_id('tblAssets')
```

Selecting the table, opening the triggers folder, and then right clicking on the trigger and disabling it allowed the update to work correctly.  I initially overlooked the triggers folder at the table level.

Comment: You should have looked in the `Triggers` folder under the table, not for database triggers. Each table has it's own triggers.

Comment: @MichaelSuede Yes, there is. It's normally after the `Constraints` folder.

Comment: Yeah I just found the listing for them.  Now I feel like an idiot LOL.  Oh well, that's what this place is for.

Comment: @MichaelSuede   Thanks for the update:  I always hate it when I don't find out the right answer to questions like this...